# Wanting to send user to another page with a certain state in react

Tags: reactjs, button, state, react-router-dom

So i've got this button on my homepage, which works great:

```
  <Link to="/pageItShouldRedirectTo">
    <button class="buttonStyling">
      Click to read article 3
    </button>    
  </Link>
```

It sends the user to pageItShouldRedirectTo perfectly. On pageItShouldRedirectTo  I have a list of buttons that render different components in a space below:

```
function ArticleSelection() {

const [displayComponent, setDisplayComponent] = useState(null);


return (
    <Button onClick={() => setDisplayComponent(<Article1/>)}>Click to see Article 1</Button>
    <Button onClick={() => setDisplayComponent(<Article2/>)}>Click to see Article 2</Button>
    <Button onClick={() => setDisplayComponent(<Article3/>)}>Click to see Article 3</Button>


{displayComponent}

)}

export default ArticleSelection
```

This section works great on it's own as well. I click a button and it renders the component in {displayComponent}. But when I use the button on the homepage, I want it to send it with article 3 already rendered.

I've experimented a few ways and haven't been able to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ideas how to solve this:

1. The most simple, and the least versatile is to "lift the state up", as described [here in the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#:%7E:text=In%20React%2C%20sharing%20state%20is,called%20%E2%80%9Clifting%20state%20up%E2%80%9D.). Move up the state, which contains info about which article is displayed, to the common parent.
2. Use react context (or any library for shared state storage, like react-redux). [Here is react context documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can set, which article is displayed in such shared state storage.
3. Pass data in the url:

*in the source component:*

```
import url from 'url'

const whereToRedirect = url.format({
  pathname: `/pageItShouldRedirectTo`,
  query: {
    article: "third",
  },
})

// whereToRedirect should look something like this: /pageItShouldRedirectTo?article=third

...

<Link to={whereToRedirect }>
  <button class="buttonStyling">
    Click to read article 3
  </button>    
</Link>
```

*in the target component:*

```
const search = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search)
const article = search.get("article")
```

Dont forget wrap with [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) to ensure props.location exists or use [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.
Also, you can use [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) instead of `Link` to redirect, which is more convenient in this case.